# Installing Python module sip 4.19.1 on Windows 7

Tags: python, sip

I've got a problem with installing SIP 4.19.1.

What I have done by now:

`- installed Anaconda (for Python 3.6) with compiled SIP 4.18,
- pip install sip
"Successfully installed sip-4.19.1" 
- and nothing, still 4.18 exists only (sip -V).`

Same thing when I downloaded Python 3.6:

`- no sip installed,
- pip install sip,
- still no sip.
- downloaded manually SIP:
  * cmd > cd sip_dir > python configure.py,
  * make (here's going into insane loop cd sipgen > make and again)
  * so installed VC,
  * nmake (here comes an error with headers but I've fixed it) 
  * nmake install > error`